# How to fix Kernel Compiler Error: expected __ before ___

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel

My module is supposed to loop through system tasks using the for_each_process macro. However, I keep getting syntax errors but I'm not sure why.

I get 3 error messages that seem to point back to the macro itself. https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9oWe.jpg

Removing the for_each_process macro allows compilation to succeed.
Below is the code. The kernel module is named tasks_manager.c
I"ve also included the code for the Makefile

```
/************tasks_manager.c**************/
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int simple_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Kernel Module\n");
    return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Kernel Module\n");
}

struct task_struct *task;

for_each_process(task)
{
    printk("Name: %s, pid: [%d]", task->comm, task->pid);
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);



/**** the Makefile's code ****/
obj-m += tasks_manager.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've defined as a for_each_process is neither a function nor a macro. If you want a macro, define it as follows:

```
#define for_each_process(task) \
{ \
    printk("Name: %s, pid: [%d]", task->comm, task->pid); \
} \
```

If you want a function, then specify return type as well as parameter type:

```
void for_each_process(struct task_struct *task)
{
    printk("Name: %s, pid: [%d]", task->comm, task->pid);
}
```